# How to reduce gap between bootstrap input elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to reduce gaps between form input elements.

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/la8RLL9IUn)

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal width-500 center-block theme-font" role="form">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">

        <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-4">Guardian Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3 form-inline">
            <select class="form-control" id="village" required="required">
                <option>S/O</option>
                <option>D/O</option>
                <option>W/O</option>
                <option>C/O</option>
            </select>
            <div class="required-icon">
                <div class="text">*</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5 form-inline float-left">
            <input class="form-control" required="required" id="name" placeholder="Guardian Name" type="text">
            <div class="required-icon">
                <div class="text">*</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Easiest would be to remove the required icon from the dropdown and remove both float-left. Then remove the cols, as they give a width.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get hacky with it (will have to add in the other input types later on), you could add this to the CSS:

```
select, input {
  min-width: 100%; /* Force element to take up the whole column width */
}

.required-icon {
  position: absolute; /* Allow icon to stack within the 100% min-width input fields */
  right: 0; /* Force it to the right side of the block */
  top: 4px; /* Quick position fix */
}

.tooltip {
  left: -70px !important; /* Override and bring the tooltip behind the input fields */
}
```

Hopefully this helps.  Liked noted above, you will have to add the extra input fields (textarea, etc.) to the list of selectors that append that "min-width: 100%" property.  Happy hacking.

Comment: Code Updated http://www.bootply.com/la8RLL9IUn Please can you tell me how to make Guardian name input field aligned with other fields in the form.??????

Comment: @user2217267

`#village {width: 40%; margin-right: 18px;}`

Add that line to your CSS document to achieve this.  It is extremely hacky, like I said before, so a safe bet could be achieved by adding the line below instead.

`@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-control {
    width: 97%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}`